# Placing marker of bus station on googlemap

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

I am having trouble with placing marker of bus station which was near me on my google map application.

Let say I live in New York City,I want all bus station with marker on my google map.But,i really don't know how to fetch all the bus station data of my current city(New York) and place a picker on it.I tried AppCoda tutorial and it gives me only marker of my custom search

Here : http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/

Is there any way that i can modified its "MapTask.Swift" code to get all bus station near me and place picker on each bus station?

Here is MapTask.Swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

class MapTask: NSObject {

let baseURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

var lookupAddressResults: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var fetchedFormattedAddress: String!

var fetchedAddressLongitude: Double!

var fetchedAddressLatitude: Double!

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let lookupAddress = address {
        var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
        geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)

            let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            // Get the response status.
            let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

            if status == "OK" {
                let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                print("The result is : \(dictionary)")

                // Keep the most important values.
                self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
                let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
            }
            else {
                completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call the Place Search with the [`type`](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) set to `bus_station` to limit the return to that specific type. The [response](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses) will return `results` with their details that you can use to set the Markers.